# Read cdata and html inside a tag by linqToXml

Tags: c#, html, xml, linq

I want to get rid of CDATA and i want to read the br tag.
this is my xml :

```
<body>
<![CDATA[
Apple iPhone är mycket mer än en mobil. Den är en kombination av tre enheter: en       revolutionerande mobiltelefon, en iPod i widescreenformat och en banbrytande Internetenhet.  Allt detta och mer därtill gör den till den bästa mobiltelefon du kan föreställa dig.
]]>
<br/>
<![CDATA[
Med de maskinvarufunktionerna i iPhone i kombination med världens mest avancerade   mobiloperativsystem öppnar Apple möjligheter för vad en mobiltelefon kan göra. Programmen   är helt integrerade med varandra och kan synkroniseras med din dator - oavsett om du   använder Mac eller PC. Från Multi-Touch-skärmen till det smarta tangentbordet och   sensorerna.
]]>
<br/>
</body>
```

and here is my code :

```
 public static List<string> GetDescriptionXml(string idItem)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(GetDescription(idItem));
        return (from doc in xdoc.Elements("body") select doc.Value).ToList();
    }
```

When I run this I just get the value inside the CDATA without the br tag!
I can i get the br tag too ?

Comment: `doc.value` only return the content(text) inside the xml element. <br/> is not a content but it is a **empty** xml element(i.e, it does not contain any content). if you need both cdata value and <br/>, you can use simple string replacement to get rid of `<![CDATA[`...`]]>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ultimate solution depends on all possible cases your HTML may contain. This is one possible solution :

```
.....
return (from doc in xdoc.Elements("body")
        select string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                           doc.Nodes()
                              .Select(o =>
                                      {
                                        if (o is XCData) return ((XCData)o).Value;
                                        else return o.ToString();
                                      }))
        ).ToList();
```

This solution joins all child nodes of the `<body>` by line break. For each child node, if it is a `CData` section the value will be taken for `String.Join()` operation. Else, if it is `<br/>` or anything other than `CData` the entire markup will be taken.

In case you want to treat other child nodes type differently, you can easily modify the `if ... else ...` part according to your needs.

Comment: excellent solution! can you please specify the advantages of using linq over normal string replacement?